# MySQL syntax error when creating a table with data from two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I am creating a new table with data from another table. I would like to combine the values from an Income_Ledger table as well as an Expenditure_Ledger table, with a WHERE condition, into a new table.

I can successfully add the values if only using one of the tables, but I can’t seem to write the SQL syntax to perform the input from both tables. i.e. the AS SELECT, FROM, WHERE works if only using one of the two tables.

Thanks for any help

*MySQL (ver 14.14 Distr 5.7.23)*

```
# bank in for below gives strings of: B1 and B2
for bank in Bank_Account_Code:
    with engine.connect() as con:
        con.execute('''
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '''+bank+''';''')
        con.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '''+bank+'''
        AS SELECT id,Date,CR
        FROM Income_Ledger
        WHERE DR_code="'''+bank+'''"

        AS SELECT id,Date,DR
        FROM Expenditure_Ledger
        WHERE CR_code="'''+bank+'''"

        ORDER BY Date
        ;''')
```

[image]

Comment: Creating a separate table for each entity is a *really* bad idea under most circumstances.  Please explain what problem you are trying to do.

Comment: Create a view instead. No copying of data needed, will always be up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant simply select two tables and put them into one.
Depending on how you want to combine the data you can either JOIN the tables, or use UNION. Seeing the CR_code in the two tables, UNION is your best bet for this situation.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: ```for bank in Bank_Account_Code:
    with engine.connect() as con:
        con.execute('''
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `'''+bank+'''`
        ;''')
        con.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '''+bank+'''
        SELECT id, Date, DR_code, DR, CR, CR_code FROM Income_Ledger
        WHERE DR_code="'''+bank+'''"
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, Date, DR_code, DR, CR, CR_code FROM Expenditure_Ledger
        WHERE CR_code="'''+bank+'''"
        ORDER BY DATE
        ;''')```